# Match only ! in a string

Tags: regex, string, matlab

what if I have this string `S= hello! are u ok!? yes ! good !!`
and I would like to capture only the exclamation mark but not !? nor !!?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind and lookahead assertion like below.

```
(?<![?!])!(?![?!])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rN3fB5/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<![?!])` Negative lookbehind  which asserts that the match would be preceded by any but not of `?` or `!`
- `!` Matches the literal `!` symbol.
- `(?![?!])` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match would be followed by any but not of `?` or `!` symbols.

Comment: does matlab support lookbehind?

Comment: yes it works !!! thanks a lot...I was in the right way to use lookbehind but I was not able to put it in the right form :)

Comment: If I need to do the same but with question mark? and don't capture sequences like !? ?! ?!?! !?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
[^!](!)(?!!)
```

Try this.This should do it.Grab the capture.See dmeo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/8